# How do I get a copy of the Android overflow menu icon?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

How do I get a copy of Android's overflow menu icon to use in a custom menu.

[image: The icon in the circle]

Comment: download the android SDK and you can find the image in there. It is added automatically to your application when you can no longer fit anymore items on the actionbar

Comment: A simple search of the docs or SO would show exactly where they are

Comment: Can you tell the path in the SDK. I can't find it. Yeah, I know that part. But I am trying to force it, so I need the icon.

Comment: to force it all you have to do it set all your menu items to never visible `android:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: [Rounded overflow icon in 5 sizes and all 14 colors](https://plus.google.com/109726284197282147930/posts/1BNteEadaBp) maybe useful to someone.

Comment: Add vector asset "ic_more_vert_24dp". Find it here too: https://design.google.com/icons/index.html (Would post this as an answer but can't b/c question is closed.)

Comment: @blizzard your link is no longer working

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Can somebody please provide a link to download the overflow menu icon?

http://developer.android.com

Once you have downloaded the SDK, you will find your images in:

```
$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/$PLATFORM/data/res/$DRAWABLE/ic_menu_moreoverflow*
```

where:

- `$ANDROID_SDK` is wherever you installed your SDK
- `$PLATFORM` is some platform directory (e.g., `android-17`)
- `$DRAWABLE` is some major drawable directory (e.g., `drawable-hdpi`)

There are different versions of the image for light and dark themes and whether or not the button has the focus.

Comment: is it safe to do `android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow"`? Eclipse doesn't suggest it and when I use it, the Layout Preview show me "another kind of overflow".

Comment: @gian1200: That icon is part of the SDK *distribution*, but not part of the Android APIs. Hence, you should copy the requisite files into your own project, if you wish to reuse the icons.

Comment: These days, AppCompat provides: @drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha (which is ready for tinting!). https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v7/appcompat/res/drawable-hdpi

Comment: Direct link to download the "3 dots" / "more vert" drawables: https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=more_vert&style=baseline