# Overflow menu in listview items

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, overflow

I have Listview. And I want to add overflow menu to each listview's item. How to do it? Now I add button to every item and show dropdown menu when user clicks on this button. But I want to replace this ordinary button with overflow one.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an ImageView or Button to trigger the menu on the right of your listview items. To get the "overflow" icon, see this question: [How do I get a copy of the Android overflow menu icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557183/how-do-i-get-a-copy-of-the-android-overflow-menu-icon)
2. Add an onClickListener to your ImageView or Button
3. On your onCreate() method, create a popup menu like this:

   popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.anchor));
   popupMenu.getMenu().add(...);
   popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
4. In your onClickListener trigger the display of the popup menu

   popupMenu.show();

Comment: what is R.id.anchor?