# Adding the Source to the Popup Menu

Tags: android

I am reading over the documentation for the [Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). I have an ImageView in my xml layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
    android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

I am getting the error "Cannot Resolve Symbol '@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark'". In my res/drawable folder, there is no such icon named ic_overflow_holo_dark. Yet, it appears in the documentation. Is this graphic provided by Android? How can I get the Popup src icon?

This is what my app/build.gradle looks like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.menuloop.menuloopandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: chk your folder mipmap

Comment: @AmodGokhale all it contains is ic_launcher.png. Is it supposed to have more icons? This is within Android Studio.

Comment: File > Project Structure on Intellij Idea with Android Studio plugin will give you the path of your Android SDK installation.

Comment: And then res > right click > New > Image Asset > Asset Type > Image. Path. The path on Mac OSX: Applications/android-sdk-macosx/android-23/data/res  and once in there, search for the icon you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a drawable named ic_overflow_holo_dark in your `drawable` res folder. `@drawable` prefix specifies that it should look in your app resources. To specify android drawables, you need to use `@android:drawable` prefix.

Comment: So I am supposed to create my own ic_overflow_holo_dark icon? I am just looking for the three-dotted flyout menu that is already available in the ActionBar. But I want to add that icon to this ImageView.

Comment: Yes. If you want a copy of the android drawable, you can check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557247/8064335

Comment: The fact that I can see the icon in the ActionBar, doesn't that suggest that the icon is already included in the SDK I am using? I am on Mac OSX.

Comment: Yes you are right. The icon is already available in your SDK. This is also available as a vector drawable. Right click on your res folder, select New -> Vector Asset. Click the Icon button, select Navigation in the left pane and look for more vert. I am using Android Studio 2.3.2 with updated platform and support libraries. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your last comment was helpful. Interesting why Android Studio doesn't just make these icons available in the search path, so you don't have to go the process you described above.

Comment: Also thanks for the distinction between @ android:drawable and @ drawable. Note that ic_overflow_holo_dark is not present in @ android:drawable either.